# Get custom term link archive with prefix

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy, terms

I am trying to get the link of custom term.

The problem that I have prefix for all urls set in `Permalinks` like that

```
/blog/%category%/%postname%/
```

So I have following links for default terms

```
http://example.net/blog/tag/development/
```

It works great.

But I have registered custom taxonomy using `register_taxonomy` function.

I try to get taxonomy archive url

```
get_term_link($term_id);
```

This function returns link in the following format

```
http://example.net/my_term/test2/
```

And this link works perfectly, but I need it to be

```
http://example.net/blog/my_term/test2/
```

How can I achieve this ?

**EDIT**

Arguments used to register taxonomy

```
 /* Set up the arguments for the my_taxonomy taxonomy. */
        $args = array(
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'query_var' => 'my_taxonomy',

            /* Only 2 caps are needed: 'manage_my_taxonomy' and 'edit_posts'. */
            'capabilities' => array(
                'manage_terms' => 'manage_my_taxonomy',
                'edit_terms' => 'edit_posts',
                'delete_terms' => 'edit_posts',
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts',
            ),

            /* The rewrite handles the URL structure. */
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'my_taxonomy',
                'with_front' => false,
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'ep_mask' => EP_NONE
            ),

            /* Labels used when displaying taxonomy and terms. */
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('My Taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'singular_name' => __('My Taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'menu_name' => __('My Taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'name_admin_bar' => __('My Taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'search_items' => __('Search my_taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'popular_items' => __('Popular my_taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'all_items' => __('All My Taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit My Taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'view_item' => __('View My Taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'update_item' => __('Update My Taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New My Taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'new_item_name' => __('New My Taxonomy Name', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate my_taxonomy with commas', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or remove my_taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
                'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from the most used my_taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy'),
            )
        );

        /* Register the 'my_taxonomy' taxonomy. */
        register_taxonomy('my_taxonomy', array('post'), $args);
```

Comment: What are the arguments you used to register the taxonomy?

Comment: @Milo thanks for comment I have just added taxonomy registration code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your permalink structure prefix is controlled by the `with_front` argument:

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'my_taxonomy',
    'with_front' => true, // changed to include prefix
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'ep_mask' => EP_NONE
),
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, now link is correct, but results in 404 error. What can be wrong ?

Comment: flush_rewrite_rules(); helped to solve the problem !!